# How do I move the turtle in LOGO?

Tags: turtle-graphics, logo-lang

How do I move the [turtle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_graphics) in [LOGO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logo_(programming_language))?

Comment: Don't forget PENUP and PENDOWN. Otherwise you'll move the turtle, but not see his track.
Also change the color of the pen, and the background color of the paper.

Comment: You go here...
http://www.sonic.net/~nbs/webturtle/webturtle.cgi

Answer (score 234, accepted):

```
// MOVE FORWARD
FD 75
// TURN RIGHT
RT 54
// TURN LEFT
LT 21
// MOVE BACKWARD
BK 17
```

Check out some other turtle commands found [here](http://gaza.freehosting.net/logo/index.html)...

---

## Turtle Commands

- `BACK ## [BK]` - Move turtle back
- `BACKGROUND ## [BG]` - Set Background color (0-15)

  - 0 - Black
  - 1 - White
  - 2 - Red
  - 3 - Cyan
  - 4 - Purple
  - 5 - Green
  - 6 - Blue
  - 7 - Yellow
  - 8 - Orange
  - 9 - Brown
  - 10 - Light Red
  - 11 - Grey 1
  - 12 - Grey 2
  - 13 - Light Green
  - 14 - Light Blue
  - 15 - Grey 3
- `CLEARSCREEN [CS]` - Clear Screen without moving turtle
- `DRAW` - Clear Screen and take turtle home
- `EACH` - Tell several sprites, whose numbers are in a list, to accept commands in a second list, e.g. `EACH [1 2] [SQUARE 10]`
- `FORWARD ## [FD]` - Move turtle forward
- `FULLSCREEN` - Full graphics screen (same as pressing F5)
- `HEADING` - Output turtle heading as a number (0-359)
- `HIDETURTLE [HT]` - Make turtle invisible
- `HOME` - Move turtle to center of screen pointing up
- `LEFT [LT]` - Turn turtle left
- `NODRAW [ND]` - Enter text mode with clear screen
- `NOWRAP` - Prevent drawings from wrapping around screen
- `PENCOLOR [PC]` - Change pen color
- `PENDOWN [PD]` - Turtle leaves trail
- `PENUP [PU]` - Turtle ceases to leave trail
- `RIGHT ## [RT]` - Turn turtle right
- `SETHEADING [SETH]` - Set turtle heading, e.g. `SETH 180`
- `SETSHAPE` - Set the current sprite shape (0-7)
- `SETX` Move the turtle to the specified x co-ordinates e.g. `SETX 50`
- `SETXY` Move the turtle to the specified x, y co-ordinates Eg. `SETXY 50 50`
- `SETY` Move the turtle to the specified y co-ordinate, e.g. `SETY 50`
- `SHAPE` - Output number of current sprite's shape
- `SHOWTURTLE [ST]` - Make turtle visible
- `SPLITSCREEN` - Mixed graphics and text screen (same as pressing F3)
- `STAMPCHAR` - Make the turtle stamp a character at the current location, e.g. `STAMPCHAR "A`
- `TELL` - Tell designated sprite to receive commands, e.g. `TELL 2`
- `TEXTSCREEN` - Use whole screen for text (same as pressing <kbd>F1</kbd>)
- `TOWARDS` - Output heading for turtle to face an X,Y coordinate, e.g. `TOWARDS 0 0`
- `WRAP` - Make turtle drawings wrap around the screen
- `XCOR` - Output current x co-ordinate of turtle
- `YCOR` - Output current y co-ordinate of turtle
- `ASPECT` - Set verticle screen scale factor, default is 0.76

---

*Samples taken directly from website: http://gaza.freehosting.net/logo/index.html*

Answer (score 52):

Logo is **all about** moving the turtle... you give it [commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logo_(programming_language)#Syntax) like this:

```
Forward 100
Right 45
```

You can do stuff like repeating commands too:

```
Repeat 8 [Forward 100 Right 45]  ; Draw an octagon
```

(What do I win? 8-)

Answer (score 11):

Whoa! Is it still around?

```
fd 300 // Forward
rt 90  // Right 90°
fd 300 
lt 90  // Left 90°
```

That used to work.

Answer (score 6):

I've seen a few LOGO implementations where you can use localized commands like:

- NAPRZOD (FORWARD),
- LEWO (LEFT),
- PRAWO (RIGTH)

or even NAPRZÓD (with Polish letter Ó).

LOGO is nice language to teach kids programming in their native spoken language.

Answer (score 4):

try: `bk`(back), `fd`(forward), `ld`(left turn in degrees), `rt`(right turn).

Answer (score 4):

By issuing commands in the correct syntax. E.G.:

```
forward 100
```

There is only one necessary command to move the turtle. It is `forward` which has the mnemonic `fd`. When working with a robot (real) turtle as opposed to a graphics based (virtual) one, you might find that the turning commands `left` and `right` [`lt` & `rt`] move the turtle a little, accidentally.

Most [implementations](http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Lisp/Logo/Implementations/) also allow the command `backwards` [`bk`].

When the turtle moves, it may draw a line as it goes depending on whether the pen is up or down at the time, and whether the current pen color is different from the background color.

A graphics based (virtual) turtle can also jump around the screen with `setx`, `sety`, and `setxy`