# How do you crop an image in Expression Blend?

Tags: image, expression-blend

I know this is leaning more in the direction of a designer question, but as I am faced with developing something which requires me to crop an image, I thought I would give the question a shot.

This seems like a ridiculous question to ask, but I've look all over the IDE (Expression Blend 2) to try and find a way to crop my image, but I can't figure it out.

This seems to be very much in line with [Joel's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo) and is discussed in [Podcast 58](http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/shows/detail4148.html) in the sense that I'm a **complete** noob when it comes to designing in Expression Blend.  I am adamantly interested in figuring out the most efficient way to do this.  I found an article that describes a work flow you can go through that will produce a crop, which I added as an answer below, but I'm **really** hoping someone else will know of a quicker (less clicks) way to do something as trivial as this.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way to crop an image directly in expression Blend. Blend is not an image editing application. You need another tool for that.

What you can do though, is clipping an image if you only want to show a portion of it. Just add a rectangle on top of it right-click it, go to *path* -> *make clipping path*. 
[alt text http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/7370/example1.jpg](http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/7370/example1.jpg)

Now select the System.Windows.Controls.Image entry from the list you want to apply the clipping on and hit *Ok*

You can even use rounded rectangles, circles and custom paths to clip, but in most cases a rectangle will do the trick.

**Just ran into another way**. 
Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028519/trying-to-change-a-croppedbitmaps-sourcerect-at-runtime). It uses a CroppedBitmapClass as the source of an image. It's not actual drawing in Blend, but you can add it by hand editing Xaml. From your question it's not clear if you are creating a Silverlight or a WPF application in Expression Blend. The CroppedBitmapClass is available in WPF only.

**With the new Silverlight 3** you can use the [WritableBitmap](http://programmerpayback.com/2009/07/12/cropping-an-image-in-silverlight-3/) to do image cropping:

Comment: Thanks Sorskoot, I'm really trying to learn this for both Silverlight and WPF applications.  With the method you've described, are you still keeping the entire image in the design?  Hence, for large images where I only need a small part of it, this would not really work well, but it would work if the majority of the image was going to be viewable?

Answer (score 0):

I found an article that has steps to do an image crop, but it's very drawn out to do such a simple operation.  You would think something that MS Paint can do in a couple button clicks would be similarly easy in Blend.

Here's the [link](http://www.developingfor.net/expression/design/simple-image-cropping-in-expression-design.html).

I'm still wondering if there's an easier way to do this, however.

The other problem with this approach is that afterwards, I can't change the size of the rectangle that I'm cropping the image with, which I need to be able to do, because I have to have the image be an exact number of pixels in width and height.

Comment: I agree, but I'm trying to learn to use Blend so I can incorporate it into my development.  This is probably going to be one of MANY questions about how to do something in Blend for me =P