# Logo programming language implementations

Tags: linux, windows, macos, logo-lang

The ["joke" question Joel asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo) during [podcast #58](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/podcast-58/) made me all nostalgic for Logo, which was the second language I ever programmed in, after Basic, and which is why I never had any trouble with recursion in college.

Are there any implementations of Logo for Windows or Linux (the platforms I can use) or Mac (because I know I'm not alone in this world)?  How can I get the Logo programming language for my computer?

Comment: a chrome extension for LOGO that I developed: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/logo-turtle/dcoeaobaokbccdcnadncifmconllpihp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm teaching my kids LOGO successfully on Windows using **[Elica LOGO](http://pavel.it.fmi.uni-sofia.bg/elica/about.html)**.  (Kids ages are presently 12 and 10.)

The package's strengths include many "advanced" extensions, beyond the basic 2-dimensional turtle.  These include 3-D graphics and simple hooks into the Windows widget world.  (You can create Windows forms with buttons, etc., from within your LOGO code.)

Lacks sound/music capability, at least in version 5.5, and the built-in documentation is extensive, with many advanced examples, but it's not very useful in my opinion--due to its incompleteness, and its having many coding examples that contain errors.   (But my kids learn more by finding the errors in the programing samples.)

Answer (score 14):

Fire up a terminal on Mac or Linux, and type `python`, then press Return or Enter. Then type `from turtle import *`, then Return or Enter. Now type `fd(100)`, then Return or Enter. Hooray! Logo with Python! =D (Windows users can install Python [here](https://www.python.org/))

### Documentation

For a complete list of commands, see the [online documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/turtle.html). Note that the documentation will tell you to type `turtle.fd(100)`, rather than `fd(100)`, because they chose to use `import turtle`, rather than `from turtle import *`. The star method is almost always bad, because it makes it possible to confuse your own functions with those in the module, but in this case it is good, because it lets us control the turtle with proper logo commands.

### Saving logo functions

Create a file called `shapes.py`, and save it somewhere sensible. Add the following code to `shapes.py`:

```
from turtle import *

def square(size):
    for i in range(4):
        fd(100)
        rt(90)

def fun(size):
    for i in range (10):
        square (size)
        rt(36)
```

Now, whenever you want to do logo, navigate to wherever you saved `shapes.py` before running `python`. Then, after running `python`, run `from shapes import *` instead of `from turtle import *`. This will import logo along with any custom functions you have defined in `shapes.py`. So, whenever you make a cool function, just save it in `shapes.py` for future use.

e.g. interactive session (after running `python` from the relevant directory):

```
from shapes import *

square(100)
fun(50)
```

Comment: I actually made my own python module so that my sister could create and SAVE logo shapes. Instead of typing `from turtle import *`, I made a .py script in the home directory of my Pi, and she could type `from <module_name> import *`. Inside the module, I had the `from turtle import *` line, followed by functions for various shapes. Any time she developed a new shape, she just had to add the function to the module, and it would be available to use the next time she launched Python.

Comment: Have you published that module? Set it up on https://github.com or similar so you can share it with us!

Comment: I don't know if I still have it. It was just a .py file beginning with `from turtle import *`, followed by some simple function definitions. (e.g. `def square(size):`)

Comment: @MestreLion I have added basic instructions for creating the module to the answer above.

Answer (score 12):

Cross-platform versions:
http://www.mathcats.com/gallery/logodownloadinfo.html

MacOS X specific:
http://www.alancsmith.co.uk/

Open-source Logo:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/fmslogo
http://www.rz.uni-augsburg.de/~micheler/en/

Comment: +1 for ACSLogo, I'd been playing with XLogo on the Mac and finding it very limited.

Answer (score 11):

[UCBLogo](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~bh/logo.html) is my favorite LOGO implementation, and happens to be available for Windows, UNIX (with X11 support for turtle drawing), and Mac OS X, with outdated ports for DOS and Mac OS 9 as well.

Most Linux distros [already](http://packages.debian.org/ucblogo) [have](http://packages.gentoo.org/package/dev-lang/ucblogo) [it](http://www.novell.com/products/linuxpackages/opensuse/ucblogo.html) [packaged](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/packages/name/ucblogo).

It is also still maintained (thanks to <s>cheap labor</s> students at Berkeley), open-source, and very portable (I've run it on various flavors of UNIX, including Linux, and various processor architectures as well).

UCBLogo comes with a fairly comprehensive standard library and good documentation; the source code for the examples in Brian Harvey's "Computer Science Logo Style" books are also included.

---

Addendum:

[papert - logo in your browser](http://logo.twentygototen.org/) is surprisingly featureful, and seems to work in any modern browser.

Comment: This site no longer seems to exist.

Answer (score 5):

KTurtle - http://edu.kde.org/applications/school/kturtle/ is what you need under linux.

for windows version of kturtle visit windows.kde.org

Answer (score 4):

The best way to teach kids logo now it through TurtleAcademy http://turtleacademy.com .
That's a really cool site for starting learning the logo principles and it's free

Answer (score 3):

To really recreate the nostalgia, you might try running Logo on an emulated Apple II.  You can get images of [Apple II disks for Logo here](http://mirrors.apple2.org.za/ftp.apple.asimov.net/images/programming/logo/) and [the AppleWin emulator here](http://applewin.berlios.de/).

Comment: good point, except that I had a C64

Answer (score 2):

There is a pure-Python version of Logo available at http://pylogo.org/

Comment: If you just want to move the turtle, you can use TurtleWorld in Swampy. http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/swampy/install.html

Comment: pylogo link is dead. Looks like it's on sourceforge at http://pylogo.sourceforge.net/ but doesn't look active.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good free one for windows
http://www.softronix.com/logo.html

And there's a parellel logo you might look at
http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/

Also, MIT has a good parallel logo called starlogo
http://education.mit.edu/starlogo/

Answer (score 0):

http://tortue-logo.fr is a browser version of the logo language. It is developped in javascript with raphaeljs (server side with python/django but the interpreter is running on the client side).

It only makes possible to play with the turtle but it may be enough to remind you good time learning how to program. :) i think it should cover the main commands of the LOGO language.

Currently french and english are supported. The french version of LOGO is different from the english one (commands are translated in french). SO make sure to choose the right language on the site.

I hope you'll enjoy

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.logointerpreter.com. It's a web based interpreter using HTML5 and JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Turtle academy online is a god source for learning and experimenting logo

Comment: Could you post some relevant content?