# Which LOGO implementation?

Tags: logo-lang

I want to show my young cousin (12) programming.
I think that LOGO is a good start. 
Which implementation should I use? (windows)

Comment: And I will go for PHP - thevbdeveloper ;)

Comment: Well, I'd stay with your idea of starting with something that has "immediate grat.", but today these may be the free Turbo Pascal or Visual Studio Express, free to download and install.

You could show how to program a user interface, and how to gradually add more logic to it.  Teach UI basics for a few days, let him/her experiment, and then add some simple OnClick level functionality, advance from there...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What modern version of LOGO should I use to teach a child programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617947/what-modern-version-of-logo-should-i-use-to-teach-a-child-programming)

Answer (score 7):

I would use this for windows

1. http://fmslogo.sourceforge.net/
2. http://www.softronix.com/logo.html
3. Others here: [Logo programming language implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020890/logo-programming-language-implementations)

I wouldn't teach Visual Basic to a person or child that is starting to program, a non static language it's preferred. Also I won't teach PHP to anyone, but that's a personal taste.

You can also take a look at Alice. Which is a language some people also use to teach kids.

http://www.alice.org/

Comment: `+1` for recommending not to teach the kid PHP

Answer (score 2):

You might want to also consider "Small Basic": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/ff384126.aspx

I have no experience with it, so I might be a bit off-base, but it seems to have a few fans:

- [Microsoft programming language for children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280918/microsoft-programming-language-for-children/2280935#2280935)
- http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/microsoft-small-basic-for-.net/

Answer (score 1):

Starlogo TNG is a good graphical implementation of Logo that can make it really fun for kids to learn.  It uses a block-programming interface and 3D graphics so it looks to kids like they're immediately playing a game.  http://education.mit.edu/drupal/starlogo-tng

Something else I've used before is RAPTOR, which is a flowchart interpretor.  It's good for teaching algorithms at a high level without having to spend time learning syntax.  http://raptor.martincarlisle.com/