# How do I hide the turtle in LOGO?

Tags: turtle-graphics, logo-lang

How do I hide the [turtle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_graphics) in [LOGO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logo_(programming_language))?

Comment: What are you experimenting on SO?

Comment: hide turtle, or ht, if I recall correctly.

Comment: [Turtle commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo/1003856#1003856)

Comment: why was this closed?  it seems like a legit question...

Comment: yeah c'mon yo.  you're making this an unfriendly place.

Comment: Seems a bit off for you to be asking this question given that you answered it already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo/1003856#1003856

Comment: Someone is trying to make a point I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
HIDETURTLE [HT] - Make turtle invisible
```

*Taken directly from website: http://gaza.freehosting.net/logo/index.html*