# Best PHP podcasts

Tags: php, podcast

What are some good podcasts on PHP and MySQL?

Answer (score 5):

There's of course dedicated [PHP Podcasts](http://www.phppodcasts.com/) site, which is an aggregator for PHP oriented podcasts.

Answer (score 5):

**iBuildings TechPortal**
An excellent podcast about PHP development. Most of the episodes are recordings from conference presentations.

http://techportal.inviqa.com/
I especially loved this episode: http://techportal.inviqa.com/2010/02/16/surviving-a-plane-crash-2/ where the developers of a Yahoo! like portal for the Netherlands talked about scalability and localization.

***Podcasts that are about programming, but not exclusively PHP***

**Floss Weekly** http://twit.tv/FLOSS
Where you can hear an interview from the inventor of PHP http://twit.tv/floss12

**Software Engineering Radio** http://www.se-radio.net/
Great, in depth, more than web programming topics (I learn about how big programming is)

**Stackoverflow Podcast** https://blog.stackoverflow.com/
Jeff and Joel cover some technical topics like proxy servers, scaling, server hardware, and how to move a turtle in the LOGO programing language. [How do I move the turtle in LOGO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo) (look who asked the question)

*NOTE:* I answered this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611363/dedicated-podcast-for-php-beginners/2731371#2731371) and saw the duplicate reference to this question. I wanted to add the same answer to this question since it is floating to the top as the prime.