# Dedicated podcast for PHP beginners

Tags: php, podcast

I'm looking for any PHP/programming podcast episodes which specifically talk about PHP classes and objects. Maybe this is too specific but any reference is ok.

BTW, are there any dedicated podcasts for PHP beginners?

Comment: Hopefully, the website show the size infomation of the podcast file . I got bad internet download speed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172327/best-php-podcasts - duplicate, community wiki style post. This has some real answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**iBuildings TechPortal** An excellent podcast about PHP development. Most of the episodes are recordings from conference presentations.

http://techportal.inviqa.com/
I especially loved this episode: http://techportal.inviqa.com/2010/02/16/surviving-a-plane-crash-2/ where the developers of a Yahoo! like portal for the Netherlands talked about scalability and localization.

***Podcasts that are about programming, but not exclusively PHP***

**Floss Weekly**  http://twit.tv/FLOSS
Where you can hear an interview from the inventor of PHP http://twit.tv/floss12

**Software Engineering Radio** http://www.se-radio.net/
Great, in depth, more than web programming topics (I learn about how big programming is)

**Stackoverflow Podcast**  https://blog.stackoverflow.com/
Jeff and Joel cover some technical topics like proxy servers, scaling, server hardware, and  how to move a turtle in the LOGO programing language. [How do I move the turtle in LOGO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo) (look who asked the question)

Answer (score 2):

its not necessary for beginners but you can check out:

- http://www.phppodcasts.com/
- http://devzone.zend.com/tag/PHP%20Abstract

Comment: Hmmm, php abstract, I can't find it on the web any more, but phppodcasts works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial and set of videos seems to match your question: [Object Oriented PHP for Beginners](http://www.killerphp.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php/).

Answer (score -6):

Podcasts are for gossip not for learning a new language. If you want to learn read the [PHP documentation](http://es.php.net/manual/en/).

Comment: Please, that's a rather elitist statement. I've found railscasts.com to be invaluable in learning Ruby on Rails, I'm sure there are some hands-on PHP podcasts out there that help get your feet wet with PHP Object Oriented programming.

Comment: I stand for my words. Read the docs! Thousand of PHP developers did it before you.

Comment: Irrelevant. Did you read a dictionary to learn english? There are many valid avenues to learn how to program. Class instruction, podcast instruction, videos, DVDs, tutuorials, books and so on. I use php.net frequently for reference but this is a perfectly valid question from someone who has found an instruction method that he believes is useful for him.

Comment: As a former PHP developer who did learn by reading the documentation, I'm all for the OP's quest to find learning materials that fit the way he learns best. Why in the world would you consider choice and variety a bad thing?

Comment: Variety has nothing to do with it. I just dont consider podcasts a valid method of learning a programming language, especially for a beginner. You may get some concepts through it, but without proper effort put in READING and WRITING CODE I dont think you can learn it.