# What is the meaning of curly braces?

Tags: python, curly-braces, parentheses, braces

Just starting to figure Python out. I've read this question and its responses:

[Is it true that I can't use curly braces in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936190/is-it-true-that-i-cant-use-curly-braces-in-python)

and I still can't fathom how curly braces work, especially since pages like Simple Programs:

http://wiki.python.org/moin/SimplePrograms

use curly braces all over the place. I understand square brackets and regular curved parentheses, but I don't know what's meant by "defining dictionaries" or what they're supposed to represent.

Comment: `from __future__ import braces`

Comment: You should really go through the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/).

Comment: Curly braces are used for [empty/non-empty dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) as well as [non-empty sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) _both_. For initializing _empty_ sets `set()` statement is used instead.

Comment: Related post - [Is it true that I can't use curly braces in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1936190/465053)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

"Curly Braces" are used in Python to define a dictionary. A dictionary is a data structure that maps one value to another - kind of like how an English dictionary maps a word to its definition.

Python:

```
dict = {
    "a" : "Apple",
    "b" : "Banana",
}
```

They are also used to format strings, instead of the old C style using %, like:

```
ds = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
x = ['has_{} 1'.format(d) for d in ds]

print x

['has_a 1', 'has_b 1', 'has_c 1', 'has_d 1']
```

They are not used to denote code blocks as they are in many "C-like" languages.

C:

```
if (condition) {
    // do this
}
```

**Update:** In addition to Python's `dict` data types Python has (since Python 2.7) [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) as well, which uses curly braces too and are declared as follows:

```py
my_set = {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Comment: Is there any way to get Python to use them for code blocks? Seemingly mad question, I know, but I'm helping a local blind kid transition from [this](https://blogs.microsoft.com/ai/project-torino-microsoft-creates-physical-programming-language-inclusive-visually-impaired-children/) to the language his friends use at school (Python) and white-space indentation on a screen reader is just horrible

Comment: @dumbledad Did you find anything? It seems like a Python-aware screen-reader is called for here - but can it be found?

Comment: Curly-braces are also used to denote [set literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#set-displays), which are like dictionary literals, only without any keys or colons (:).

Comment: @dumbledad you can try this: https://github.com/ofajardo/pytwister

Comment: @dumbledad: https://python-with-braces.appspot.com/

Comment: Python 3.6 introduced the use of formatted string('f') with curly braces, like so:  varName = "Python" print (f"Hello, {varName}")

Answer (score 23):

In Python, curly braces are used to define a dictionary.

```
a={'one':1, 'two':2, 'three':3}
a['one']=1
a['three']=3
```

In other languages, { } are used as part of the flow control. Python however used indentation as its flow control because of its focus on readable code.

```
for entry in entries:
     code....
```

There's a little easter egg in Python when it comes to braces. Try running this on the Python Shell and enjoy.

```
from __future__ import braces
```

Comment: `from __future__ import braces` gives `SyntaxError: not a chance`. That's a bigger easter egg.

Answer (score 10):

In languages like `C` curly braces (`{}`) are used to create program blocks used in flow control.  In Python, curly braces are used to define a data structure called a dictionary (a key/value mapping), while white space indentation is used to define program blocks.

Answer (score 6):

Dictionaries in Python are data structures that store key-value pairs. You can use them like associative arrays. Curly braces are used when declaring dictionaries:

```
d = {'One': 1, 'Two' : 2, 'Three' : 3 }
print d['Two'] # prints "2"
```

Curly braces are not used to denote control levels in Python. Instead, Python uses indentation for this purpose.

I think you really need some good resources for learning Python in general. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/175001/10077

Comment: I've been working my way through Learn Python the Hard Way (which is apparently a bit controversial), and have reached the chapter where I'm supposed to download, print and just read code. I keep running across things I don't know, and curly braces are the only thing I can't wrap my head around when I look them up... hence the question.

Comment: @mattshepherd: Maybe it lives up to its name. 8v) Seriously, though, the [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/) (as Michael J. Barber linked) is very good. You might give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is something like an array that's accessed by keys (e.g. strings,...) rather than just plain sequential numbers. It contains key/value pairs, you can look up values using a key like using a phone book: key=name, number=value.

For defining such a dictionary, you use this syntax using curly braces, see also: http://wiki.python.org/moin/SimplePrograms