# In python 2.7, how do I detect if the value in a dictionary's (key, value) pair is an iterable itself so I iterate through it?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a dictionary (created by plistlib) that has some values which are displayed enclosed in {}. How do I detect these values and iterate through them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python, how do I determine if an object is iterable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952464/in-python-how-do-i-determine-if-an-object-is-iterable)

Comment: Do you care if it's *iterable*, or if it's *"enclosed in {}"* (a set or dictionary)? Have you considered some research?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I am unaware even of the names of those characters, much less that their presence in python output indicated a dictionary or set. I tried searching on several search engines with 'python {}', 'python "{}"', and 'python +"{}"' and none of them returned anything useful.

Comment: Many search engines don't handle special characters well. Those in particular are usually called "braces", sometimes "curly brackets" or "curly braces": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197324/curly-braces-in-python. Sets and dictionaries will be covered in most basic Python tutorials: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values displayed enclosed in `{}` like `{a: b, c: d}` are called [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). Values like `{a, b, c}` are called sets. In your case, they are dictionaries.

```
dictionary = {'a': {'b', 'c'}, 'd': 1}
for key, value in dictionary.iteritems():
    if isinstance(value, dict):  # Check if value is dictionary
        print value, "is a dictionary"
    else:
        print value, "is not a dictionary"
```

Comment: okay, I wasn't aware dictionaries could contain another dictionary inside themselves, and every search engine I tried ignored {} even if enclosed in quotes. meaning "{}". Thanks for the help.

Comment: Not necessarily, sets also use braces