# Open Bracket python

Tags: vim, neovim

Why when I open a bracket in python jump to next level
This happen:

[image: this is wrong.]

and  I want this:

[image: like javascript]

Comment: In Vim a lot is influenced by configuration and keys pressed. So what exactly must be done to reproduce this?

Comment: If you want remove your configuration just open a file ".py"  type python

Comment: 1.:    type:       {
2: type:            }
3: move your cursor between the brackets and press Enter

Comment: I can reproduce this, too. It also happens with a proper Python dictionary definition (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197324/what-is-the-meaning-of-curly-braces). It's caused by the indent script, maintained by Bram itself; it has to config setting to affect this. Is that the recommended coding style for dicts?