# What is the meaning of a for loop in curly braces?

Tags: python, for-loop, curly-braces

[what-is-the-meaning-of-curly-braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197324/what-is-the-meaning-of-curly-braces) says that they are used for dictionaries, but what about this example?

```
resp = {
    requests.get('http://localhost:8000')
    for i in range(20)
}
```

Taken from [here](http://skipperkongen.dk/2016/09/09/easy-parallel-http-requests-with-python-and-asyncio/) (actually it uses `[]`, but it works with `{}` as well). What is the meaning of this, and why is this loop upside-down?

Comment: `set` object....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Curly braces are also used for sets. This is a *set comprehension*. It creates the set of 20 `requests.get` objects, keeping only the unique ones.

If you use `[]` instead of `{}` it is a *list comprehension*. They are similar, but have two differences

- the list is *ordered*
- the list *can have* duplicate elements

Also, as you mention, *this is a bad way to make requests*. Comprehensions should be used for *creating a list/set*, not for calling a number of commands as a by-product. In that case, a simple for-loop is better, it makes the intent clearer.

Comment: Thanks... I got confused because this is a very weird way to make these calls since their return values are saved in the set but not used afterwards. Also, I always write *-comprehensions in one line, so that threw me off a bit