# What's the difference between [ ] and { } when defining a variable (Python)?

Tags: python, variables

I saw others use

```py
CurlyBraces = {'Lorem','Ipsum'}
```

for their tables in python, but some others use

```py
SquareBrackets = ['Lorem','Ipsum']
```

for their tables, what's the difference?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197324/what-is-the-meaning-of-curly-braces

Comment: First one is a set, it accepts only hashable objects, is unordered, and keeps only one occurrence of each object. The second one is a list, is ordered, can contain pretty much everything.

Comment: Beware when you see a var defined like `{}` - it's a dict, not a set. If you want to declare an empty set you have to use an explicit constructor like `set()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curly Braces creates a Set (https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp) or Dictionary, while square braces creates List (https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp).

A set is an unordered data structure, best for finding items fast, while a list is an ordered data structure

Answer (score 0):

The first one is a shorthand for a `set`, and the second for a `list`. You could also have one very similar to the first to define a `dict`.

For example, here are 2 equivalent definitions for each:

```py
# list
my_list_1 = [1, 2, "cat"]

my_list_2 = list()
my_list_2.append(1)
my_list_2.append(2)
my_list_2.append("cat")


# set
my_set_1 = {1, 2, "cat"}

my_set_2.add(1)
my_set_2.add(2)
my_set_2.add("cat")


# dict
my_dict_1 = {"animal": "cat", 42: "number", "something": 1}

my_dict_2["animal"] = "cat"
my_dict_2[42] = "number"
my_dict_2["something"] = 1
```

Also note that if you see `some_var = {}`, it means a `dict`. Sets are more rare in Python.