# Does this create an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am using the following JavaScript code:

```
var a = [23, 34, 45, 33];
```

Is `a` considered an array of integers?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why it matters?

Comment: Why, don't you wanna know how to move the turtle to the left in logo?

Comment: @Pablo: Am I missing something? Turtle? Logo?

Comment: @Marcel Korpel
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo

Comment: @Pablo: Wow, remarkable question! I now understand you meant the ancient programming language. Call me stupid, but I don't see how this is related to the question.

Comment: Well it's a bit subtle. On podcast No. 58 Joel argues that every valid question, no matter how simple it might be, it should be answered so others can find an answer to this same question.

Comment: Ah, now I see. In that case I can think of many simple questions that should be answered, too. (No, I won't do that.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, `a` is an array. However, since Javascript isn't statically typed, it can contain other types as well, such as strings, objects, other arrays and so on. Therefore, tagging it as "an array of integers" wouldn't be right.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript doesn't have an Integer type. It is an Array containing Numbers (but not limited to containing only Numbers)

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an array `a` using an [array literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Literals).

> An array literal is a list of zero or more expressions, each of which represents an array element, enclosed in square brackets ([]). When you create an array using an array literal, it is initialized with the specified values as its elements, and its length is set to the number of arguments specified.

As the other answers already pointed out, JavaScript arrays are able to contain elements of different data types.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. It really is.

Comment: @Marcelo: just curios, did you add "it really is" only to fight off the minimum 15-char limit :-) ?

Comment: @Marcelo, I hate that restriction :-) It sucks that they don't remove it at least for members above some rating. ++ on the pun

Comment: I agree, but it's a minor inconvenience, I guess.

Comment: @bobince: how did you do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question...

a is considered an array of integers as long as you want it that way since javascript is dynamically typed, ie. you could potentially do:

var a = [23, 34, 45, 33];
alert(a[0] + 1); // shows 24

a = "sometext";
alert(a + 1); // shows "sometext1"

HTH.

Answer (score -2):

Javascript supports var so you can have combination of string, int, decimal here.

To check further details see this link http://javascript.blogsome.com/category/1/javascript-array/

Comment: I think this is misleading.  Is there a necessary correlation between the keyword `var` and the fact that arrays are not statically typed?

Comment: Not at all. `var` declares a variable against the current scope (mostly local). This is totally independent of arrays, whatever they contain.