# Python dictionaries - difference between dict.get(key) and dict.get(key, {})

Tags: python, dictionary

When getting values from a dictionary, I have seen people use two methods:

`dict.get(key)`

`dict.get(key, {})`

They seem to do the same thing.  What is the difference, and which is the more standard method?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: First method returns None if the key is not present, whereas the second method returns an empty dictionary.

Comment: Run both on an empty dictionary and you will see.

Comment: The latter is usually seen when you want to also call .get on the result again.

Comment: "They seem to do the same thing" -- how so? 30 seconds of experimentation in the shell falsifies that.

Comment: Note the optional `value` argument in `dict.get()`: "Value to be returned if the key is not found. The default value is None." You can also pass in `'abcde'`, `5`, or a function call if you so desire

Comment: To all of you who have roasted me, I agree this was a stupid question in hind sight.  To those of you who answered (@wim, @Alexander, @G.Anderson), thank you!

Comment: I wouldn't say it's stupid @IntrastellarExplorer There's a strong historical precedent for having a canonical answer for some simpler programming questions.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo and its history https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/18/podcast-58/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second parameter to `dict.get` is optional: it's what's returned if the key isn't found. If you don't supply it, it will return `None`.

So:

```
>>> d = {'a':1, 'b':2}
>>> d.get('c')
None
>>> d.get('c', {})
{}
```

Comment: Thank you @Draconis.  I was using ipython, and it was masking the None returned.  This makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

> get(key[, default])
>   Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never raises a KeyError.

The typical way to look things up in a dictionary is `d[key]`, which will raise `KeyError` when the key is not present.

When you don't want to search for documentation, you can do:

```
d = {}
help(d.get)
```

which will display the docstring for the the `get` method for dictionary `d`.

Comment: I didn't know about the help() function.  Thank you @Eric Wilson!

Comment: With `ipython` the help functionality is built in even nicer -- `d.get?`